# How to translate to a specific point with rotational transformation.

Tags: geometry, transformation, rotations

Basically I have two rectangles. ABCD and EFGH

EFGH is rotated around it's centre point (X)

ABCD has centre point (W)

I also know for the sake of this example that EFGH is rotated counter clockwise at 45°

I am trying to do this for all corners but basically

What I am trying to figure out is how much do I need to translate ABCD by such that when rotated at 45° around its centre point (W), the corner B will be equal to point F. (See blue square as a rough example)

Basically Im trying to solve for what coordinates does the centre W have to be such that after rotation around it B is equal to F

[image]

I've spent ages trying to figure this out and I can't come up with anything. I'm not too familiar with matrices.

I tried calculating the distance and angle of WB, and since I know what F is i could say

```
x = WB * cos (WB°+45°)
y = WB * sin (WB°+45°)

But Fx = x + x2(origin)
And Fy = y + y2(origin)

x2 = Fx - x
y2 = Fy-y
```

Trying to solve for new 'origin' of ABCD, but to no avail..

Comment: Are the squares the same side-length?

Comment: They are not. But hypothetically I know the dimensions of both. (And coordinates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=(0,0)$ and let $W=(a,b)$. Call $S_X, S_W$ the respective squares, $S_X', S_W'$ after rotation.

$$S_X : (a\pm EF/2, b\pm EF/2)$$

$$S_W : (\pm AB/2, \pm AB/2)$$

After rotation:

$$S_X' : (a, b\pm \sqrt{2}/2EF),(a\pm \sqrt{2}/2EF, b)$$

$$S_W' : (0, \pm \sqrt{2}/2AB), (\pm \sqrt{2}/2AB,0)$$

(you can get this by multiplying the coordinates by the rotation matrix.)

If you want to line up $B$ and $F$ then you want real numbers $s,t$ such that

$$(s,  \sqrt{2}/2AB+t)=(a, b+ \sqrt{2}/2EF)$$

So $$(s,t)= (a,b+\sqrt{2}/2(EF-AB))$$

**Edit**

Here is an interactive plot I made for you. First both squares of specified length are rotated by 45 degrees. Then the square centered at the origin is translated by the amount specified above.

> https://www.desmos.com/calculator/psp0oquhfs

For rectangles, rather than go through a whole 'nother derivation, the value of $s,t$ you seek is:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}s\\ t\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}a\\ b\end{matrix}\right]+\left[\begin{matrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}F_x-B_x-a\\ F_y-B_y-b\end{matrix}\right]$$

Another example for rectangles, rotating $270^o$

> https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qccjkp32ha

Comment: Wow I will go over this in a sec. And how about for any angle? When angle isnt 45 degrees?

Comment: The process is the same. Point $B$ is sent to $$\left[\begin{matrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}B_x\\ B_y\end{matrix}\right]$$
The point $F$ is sent to
$$\left[\begin{matrix}a\\ b\end{matrix}\right]+\left[\begin{matrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}F_x-a\\ F_y-b\end{matrix}\right]$$
From there its a matter of finding $s,t$ by simple algebra as above

Comment: When checking i notice there was a problem with s and t, but realized that i made an error as they are not squares but rectangles i should have clarified that

Comment: That doesn't change the process, it only makes the algebra a bit harder

Comment: Yes that is where my issue is: figuring it out for rectangles since the sides are different. The matrix wouldnt work on the rectangles would it?

Comment: The matrix still works. The solution wouldn't looks as simple writing it in terms of the side lengths. But for specific values you can easily find $s,t$. You just want $s,t$ such that
$$B_x\cos\theta -B_y\sin\theta + s =a+\cos\theta(F_x-a)-\sin\theta(F_y-b)$$
and
$$B_x\sin\theta +B_y\cos\theta + t =b+\sin\theta(F_x-a)+\cos\theta(F_y-b)$$
edit: see answer edit

Comment: Ok i applied the matrix you showed me. However I graphed the squares and when applying the matrix you edited in above i keep getting the wrong answer. I didnt add a and b in the matrix so i could just grt the translation, and it is still not correct

Comment: It is correct. Here is an example like the other but with rectangles: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wbzfhknosz

It isn't as generalized as the square version but this is set to $F=(4,6)$, $B=(2,1)$. The value of $T$ may be changed to different angles in degrees. The way I have it set up, you must also change the upper bound of $t$ to be equal to $2\cdot T$ (desmos wont allow variables in boundaries)

Comment: Using your animation, and solving for S: s=a+cosθ(Fx−a)−sinθ(Fy−b)-Bxcosθ + Bysinθ Plugging in F(4,6) and B(2,1) and using an angle of 45° I'm getting -2.12 which is obviously wrong. What am I missing? Is F and B the original rectangle corner or do I substitute F and B AFTER they have been rotated at 45°.

Comment: $(a,b)$ is $(3,3)$ so
$$s= 3+\cos(\pi/4)(4-3)-\sin(\pi/4)(6-3)-2\cos(\pi/4)+1*\sin(pi/4) = 3-3\sqrt{2}/2 \approx 0.8786$$
now, the rotated point $B'$ has $x-$ coordinate
$$B'_x = 2\cos(\pi/4)-1\sin(\pi/4) = \sqrt{2}/2 \approx 0.707$$
Now you can verify $$B'_x+s = F'_x $$
The $F_x,B_x$ in the formula in the answer are the originals

Comment: Amazing. In my defence in my comment I said I was getting -2.12 but it WAS 0.88. Where I was having difficulty is I thought s was the X translation, so I thought 0.88 was supposed to be that X translation. It is the last two equations I have to understand fundamentally why you used them, but I'm sure you've had enough of me :P If I had enough 'rep' I would vote this up twice!

Comment: Dont worry about it, I enjoy these kinds of problems. Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: I have a quick question. Am am doing a lot of these calculations now. All is working, however I notice they only hold true when the rectangle to be translated has a centre of (0,0). What would you do outside of that realm? I'm realizing it's doing crazy things (using your animation) because its rotating everything around (0,0)

Comment: Solved my own question. I figure out deltaX and deltaY between origin of rectangle and (0,0). And I add these values to s and t respectively

Comment: Yes. Actually, I centered both rectangles. Then I offset one by adding $(a,b)$. The same would work for the other